# combining if and ifequal in django

Tags: django

I have two variables:
isAdmin (a boolean)
username (a string)

I need to evaluate whether the is an administrator OR the username equals a certain username.
I tried

```
{% if isAdmin or ifequal username 'xyz' %}
```

but I cannot get it to work.

So how do I combine a check on these two variables ?

thanks
Thomas

Comment: Check it in a nested manner. First if administration and then if equal

Comment: @karthikr That would equal to an AND operator, not OR.

Comment: oops.. i missed that or part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not combine `ifequal` with `if` but you can also write

```
{% if isAdmin or username == 'xyz' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate in your `views function` and pass it into the template

Here's a rough snippet

```
def view_function(request):
      #your code
      if isAdmin or username == 'xyz':
           arg = true
      return render_to_response('template.html', {'arg': arg})
```

In `your template`

```
{% if arg %}
```